# Unhandled Exception when i used Intent in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

i want solution for this problem when i used intent in xamarin to make android app i got this error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
btcall.Click += delegate
{
    var url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("http://www.google.com");
    var intent = new Intent(action: Intent.ActionView, uri: url);
    StartActivity(intent);
};
 btother.Click += delegate
{
    var intent = new Intent(action: Intent.ActionReboot);
    StartActivity(intent);
};
```

[image: Screenshot of My problem]

Comment: Do *not* post images of code, add the formatted code directly to your question.

Comment: i read this solution but is not work

Comment: It will when you debug your code and find out that `btcall` is null

Comment: Please place your `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.main)` behind `base.OnCreate(bundle)`.